# Burger menu clickable area too small

Tags: css, menu, anchor, nav

https://codepen.io/everybodysfeelingwonderland/full/OjyRpM/

For the mobile size of my website my burger icon for the menu has a way too small clickable area, it is only those thin lines.

I also have this problem with other anchors that I'd like to have with a bigger clickable area, but don't want the element itself to become bigger on my page.

```
<div id="burger-container">
        <div id="burger">
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#burger-container{
margin: 25px 0 0 0;
width: 50px;
float: right;
padding-right: 70px;
}

#burger{
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
}

#burger span{
background: black;
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 3px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
top: 0;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(2){
width: 0;
opacity: 0;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(3){
transform: rotate(45deg);
top: -13px;
}

#burger-container.open span:nth-child(1){
transform: rotate(-45deg);
top: 13px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding fixed width and height

```
#burger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS like so:

```
#burger{
    display: none;
    padding: 23px 15px 10px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 580px){

    #burger-container{
        float: right;
    }

    #burger{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This way you are only displaying the burger menu when the screen-width is 580px or less and the padding gives you a larger click area.

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/GvpNeQ) for example.

This is a better practice in my opinion because you don't have to mess with setting a specific width and height, just play around with the `padding`.